# How to multiple language bootstrap css

Tags: html, navbar

I use css bootstrap to create a logo

```
nav .navbar-brand::after{
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'RalewayExtralight', sans-serif;
content: 'The Public Var';
color: #0E5A63;
}
```

Now, I want multiple language 'content'. How can I do ?

Comment: I trying use javascript i18next library...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in your css code without using multiple codes. Write down the content in your html code so you can change it easy by php script